# How to eliminate duplicates rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, localhost, duplicates

Even after running query as`SELECT DISTINCT STATES` I am getting duplicates.

This is the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `STATE` FROM `bank_database` GROUP BY `STATE` ORDER BY `STATE` LIMIT 100
```

And here is the output
[image: Double Entries]

I need

```
 63      ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLAND
 7311    ANDHRA PRADESH
 150     ARUNACHAL PRADESH
 ...
 and so on
```

Here is my DB Structure.
[image: DB Structure]

Help.
Thanks in Advance.

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT BRANCH FROM `BANK`.`BANK_DATABASE` WHERE (BANK = '$bank_name' AND STATE = '$state_name' AND DISTRICT = '$district_name')"
```

The Above query is working correct for certain banks, and failing for some.

Comment: Looks like there are differences in the `state` value. Try to use `GROUP BY trim(STATE)`

Comment: Looks like you have some white space characters on some of the states. Try this first `update bank_database set STATE = trim(STATE)` and then run your query and see what you get.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty TRIM didn't affect. I tried.. `0 rows affected. (Query took 0.5445 sec)`

Comment: can you upload it on sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, there must be some spaces.

```
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, trim(STATE) FROM `bank_database` 
     GROUP BY  trim(STATE)  
     ORDER BY trim(STATE) LIMIT 100
```

if it works fine, run this query to fix your data issues.

```
 update tableName set state =  trim(state);
```

Comment: Ideally the above `update` statement should take care for all the space characters, but miraculously it did not affect my database. There are some irregularities in my data itself.

Comment: irregularities? may I know what do you mean by them?

Comment: `null` or some even have `#NAME` and `#STATE` as data instead of actual data.

Comment: Tried to make SQL Fiddle, but i have 122846 rows, so couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The data  is not really the same? There is a space in the data.

```
'ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLAND' != 'ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLAND space'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT *)` this will only count distinct values

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve above **`data anomaly`** by this query

```
UPDATE BANK_DATABASE
SET STATE = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM STATE)
WHERE STATE = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM STATE)
```

Anyways, Thanks to all.